# SQL - Remove Blanks/nulls rows and combine rows

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to combine multiple rows into as few rows as possible by removing nulls

Current:
Table1
[image: CurrentTable]

want:
Table2:
[image: WantTable]

Comment: please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and show us what you've tried and where it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample data and results you can use:

```
select column1, column2, min(column3), min(column4), . . .,
       column8
from t
group by column1, column2, column8;
```

Comment: that's what I was trying before, and again just now. I received error:

"Feature, Distinct, or Group By against long binary/varchar data #02:
dbname.#temptable1.column2, is not supported. 
--(dflib/dfo_groupby.cxx 389)
SQLCODE=-10001030, ODBC 3 State="HY000"
But, I just commented out Column2, and it works. Thank you